# How to set grouping on a wpf DataGrid that has CompositeCollection as item source?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, listcollectionview, compositecollection

I'm using c# and WPF. I have a WPF DataGrid that needs to be binded to several data sources.
What I did is create for each data source the following code:

```
var listCollectionView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myObservableCollection);
var collection = new CollectionContainer { Collection = listCollectionView };
myCompositeCollection.Add(collection);
```

'myCompositeCollection' is my items source for the grid.
I can't create one list because the data sources come from different entities and I don't want to handle the add/delete/update/reset of each observable collection.

However each different data source should be in a different group in the grid.
How do I add a grouping (even a custom implementation) instead of the regular 'GroupDescriptions' of the ICollectionView that doesn't work on CompositeCollections?

Thanks.

Comment: Nobody? Maya did you find any workaround?

Comment: The only workaround I found is that I added to the collection a 'separator' item that it's style will look like an expander. Whenever it was clicked I removed from the CompositeCollection all objects that belonged to the groupe and re added them if it was clicked again. For each change in one of the objects I recalculated to which group it belonged and changed the index accordingly. Very heavy, but didn't find another option.